# How many time-bound positive mitzvot are women obligated in?

Tags: halacha-theory, women, mitzvah, time, time-bound

Women are generally not obligated in positive mitzvot bound by time. There are some exceptions, such as eating matzah on Pesach and making kiddush on Shabbat. What other time-bound positive mitzvot are women obligated in and why?

Comment: some listed ones (though not an exhaustive list) https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mitzvot_Aseh_SheHazman_Grama

Comment: "generally" How many are they actually exempt from for this reason? 5? 6? I count Tzitzit, Shofar, Sukkah, Lulav, Shema and some say Omer. What am I missing? Everything else they are obligated in unless there is some other special exclusion (as there is for at least Tefillin, Talmud Torah, Milah, Pidyon Haben, and Pru Urvu)

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60080/759

Comment: ["many Mitzvot of the ritual-temporal variety which women are in fact fully obligated in (despite the "general rule" that they are exempt from positive time-bound commandments): prayer, blessings, grace after meals, Shabbat candles, Kiddush, Lechem Mishneh, 3 Shabbat meals, Havdalah, checking for Chametz, Mazta, Maror, Hagada, 4-cups, fast days, mourning the loss of the Temple, Megillat Esther, Mattanot LaEvyonim, Mishloach Manot, Seudat Purim, Chanukah candles, Yom Tov candles, and Simchat Yom Tov"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/245081)

Comment: @DoubleAA Generally enough to be taught as an almost unqualified mishna...

Comment: @ba is it really unheard of for a Mishna to record a rule with very few applications?

Comment: I already asked that (needs searching). To my count, there are 35 time bound positive Mitzvos (Temple works excluded), 8 of which women are exempt (including two Teffilin).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time-related Mitzvot - much more obligation than Ptur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95199/time-related-mitzvot-much-more-obligation-than-ptur)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rambam ([Hil. Avodah Zarah 12:3](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=4&perek=12&halocha=3&hilite=)) gives the following list:

וכל מצות עשה שהיא מזמן לזמן ואינה תדירה נשים פטורות חוץ מקידוש היום ואכילת מצה בלילי הפסח ואכילת הפסח ושחיטתו והקהל ושמחה שהנשים חייבות

The Avodat Hamelech ([ibid.](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=47650&rid=375)) notes a number of additional mitzvot which it seems women are obligated in as well:

מנה רבנו רק ששה מצות עשה קידוש היום, אכילת מצה, אכילת הפסח ושחיטתו והקהל ושמחה, ובאמת יש בזה מקום עיון, דלמה לא מנה גם מ"ע דתשביתו דמשמע מדברי רבנו דאיתיה גם בנשים וכן עשה דספור יציאת מצרים בליל פסח וענוי יוהכ"פ ועשה דשבתון בשבת ויו"ט ועשה דבאש תשרופו דקדשים